# How to create database table when using Wildfly?

Tags: sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I am trying to complete a tutorial on a simple javaEE project using wildfly. The first step is creating two tables in my database. As it says I should create my tables like this: "CREATE TABLE wildfly.name...." but it gives me an error saying thet wildfly is unknown.

Link to the tutorial: [click here](http://www.thejavageek.com/2015/01/09/creating-jsf-ejb-jpa-application-using-eclipse-wildfly/)

My question is why should i put "wildfly." before the table name and how can I solve this error?

Thank you for your help!

Note: I am using oracle database instead of mysql

Comment: Oracle assumes that is a schema name.  You need to create that first.

Answer (score 1):

It's a misleading MySQL tutorial example because in Oracle syntax "wildfly." is a user(schema) in the Oracle database.

Schema/user in Oracle is a namespace for tables and other objects. So, when you issue such a statement - you're telling oracle to create table in namespace WILDFLY. If you don't have such user in your database or you don't have rights to access such user/schema - you can't create tables there.

You should create such user in Oracle database (or alter your statement to another user/schema name that you actually have in your database) and put your tables there.

For example these statements are correct because I created WILDFLY user before putting tables to it:

```
CONNECT SYS/****@ORCL AS SYSDBA
CREATE USER WILDFLY IDENTIFIED BY WILDFLYPASSWORD;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO WILDFLY;
CREATE TABLE WILDFLY.MYTABLE...
```